# Can I use my pfSense WAN IP as public IP for 1:1 NAT? What about port forwarding?

Tags: firewall, nat, port-forwarding, pfsense

I have a dual pfSense configuration with CARP. Both WAN interfaces are assigned consecutive WAN IP .150, .151. I think it is silly that pfSense would require them both to have these dedicated IP so I was wondering if it is possible that I could use 1:1 NAT and add their IP as Virtual (CARP) IP in the system. So:

```
pf0 - WAN IP .150
pf1 - WAN IP .151
CARP IP0 - .150
CARP IP1 - .151
1:1 NAT Entry .150 <-> 10.1.1.150
1:1 NAT Entry .151 <-> 10.1.1.151
```

If this is not possible, can I at least forward certain requests to certain ports (HTTP/S) @ .150, .151 to appropriate servers?

```
Port forward .150:80,443 <-> 10.1.1.150:80,443
Port forward .151:80,443 <-> 10.1.1.151:80,443
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, **No**.

The IP "foot" for carp monitoring/communication is only present on ONE machine (the box it's assigned to).  By definition it is not a redundant IP, and it shouldn't really be used for serving other traffic.

Take the following scenario as an example:

- You configure port 80 on .150 (primary FW) and .151 (backup FW) to forward somewhere.
- The primary FW fails.

  - Now all traffic going to .150 is hitting a dead IP (your service on .150 is down).
- The primary FW comes back and the secondary FW fails.

  - Now the traffic going to .150 works again, but all the traffic to .151 is hitting a dead IP.

Comment: Ok - so basically, for every pfSense in your CARP subnet you are going to need to reserve a public IP (if you want failover to work).

Comment: I don't believe CARP can use the magic all-routers multicast, so if I'm right you need to burn one IP per unit in the pool.  It's entirely possible I'm wrong though - If I am I'd love to hear it as I'd get to reclaim two IPs on *my* network :-)

Comment: This answer is correct on why you can't use the interface IPs. To answer part of the OP's question, it's not "silly", it's how every router redundancy protocol functions - VRRP, HSRP, and CARP.